# Passing OAuth result from express server to react in url params

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, oauth-2.0, oauth

I have an express and react application that I am working on. The app uses an external OAuth service to get an API token.
Once the user has successfully verified themselves using OAuth, the external service calls back to the route `oauth/callback` on my express server.

I then verify the OAuth code and get back an API token for the user for their service.
My controller for the `oauth/callback` route looks bit like this.

```
const handleOAuth = async function (req, res, next) {
    try{
        const token = await oauth_service.verifyCallback(req) # This gets the api token
        # UNSURE HOW TO APPROARCH NEXT PART NOW
    }catch(error){
        logger.error(`Error has occured in the handleOAuth service ${error}`)
        res.status(500).send({message:"Internal server error has occured"})
    }
}
```

Now once I have the token I need to link it back to a user in my service which the express server does not know at the moment.

A plan I taught of was to redirect back to my frontend react project and pass the `token` as a url param that I can parse on the frontend.
I will also know my user on the frontend as it will be in my redux state.

So the above code would become

```
const handleOAuth = async function (req, res, next) {
    try{
        const token = await oauth_service.verifyCallback(req) # This gets the api token
        res.redirect(`/myroute/${token}`)
    }catch(error){
        logger.error(`Error has occured in the handleOAuth service ${error}`)
        res.status(500).send({message:"Internal server error has occured"})
    }
}
```

Then in my react router I could define a dynamic route which accepts parameters

```
function App() {
  return (
   <Router>
     <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/myroute/:token" component={MyComponent} />
      </Switch>
     </div>
   </Router> 
  );
}
```

In `MyComponent` then I could access the url parameters using the `match` prop from react-router-dom, the users information can be loaded from the redux state.

```
const MyComponent= ({match,path}) => {
    console.log(match) // Token will be in here 
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I am not saying this is a perfect solution (far from it) but anyone suggest a possibly better/more secure one possibly?

For example if anyone went to the route `/myroute/WHATEVER` this implementation would take the the string literal `WHATEVER` as being an API token. The route is not just one layer deep in reality (its about 5/6) but just highlights one of the problems.
Suggestion welcome!

Answer (score 1):

There is a custom hook for that, built-in in react-router:

```
    import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

        const MyComponent= ({match,path}) => {

//Thats the input which you defined in the <Route>
    const { token } = useParams(); 
    
            console.log(token) // Token will be in here 
            return(
                <div>
                    <h1>Hello</h1>
                </div>
            )
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll use this, you think that the general flow of data is a good design approach?

Comment: Well, I guess so, there are not many other options to get url params